# Is " \; " an escape sequence for semicolon in urls

Tags: url

Is the combination `\;` an escape sequence for semicolon i.e. `;`.

Pardon me for the shortness of the question before, actually I am using this "\;" to escape the ";" on Linux terminal and as well as windows. It is being used to separate the different parameters querystring of a URL. Using only ";" works for windows but not on Linux. However using "\;" instead of ";" works for both Linux and windows. 
The URL is being passed to some command for processing the resource pointed by URL.

My query was simply, Is '\;' a standard escape character for ';' on linux and windows console/shell ?

Comment: I do not understand anything!

Comment: When? and how java, javascript, windows, linux?

Comment: Your question seems to be about URLs, so I've replaced all the tags with "url".  If your question is actually about how to represent strings in a particular language, please feel free to edit.

Answer (score 9):

In urls, the escape symbol for `;` is `%3B`

For more information see http://www.december.com/html/spec/esccodes.html

Answer (score 1):

**No**. But the combination **\;** will give an error. I think you have to try `\\;` instead of **\;**.

Because **;** is not a escape character in Java. And with \ you can only put the escape characters. If you want some non-escape characters with \ then you have to use `\\`

Answer (score 1):

Semicolon does not need escaping in urls.

You can test it yourself in your javascript console (for Chrome, or maybe Firebug in FF) by using `encodeURI(';')`

Comment: Yes and no. Semicolon is not special in URLs themselves, but they *are* special in the parameter list in the query component (sometimes, they are used in place of `&`). Then they need to be escaped.

Answer (score 0):

No. In URLs, you escape by %XX where XX is the hex code of the character you want. You can get the correctly escaped string easily in javascript by using the `escape()` or `encodeURIComponent()` functions.

[See this other question for more](https://stackoverflow.com/q/332872/51831)

Answer (score 0):

Your url read pass the arugumnets encodeURIComponent